# search results as links to a php page

Tags: php

for the sake of this question, consider how ebay links the results of a search to a more detailed description of an auction through the name and image of a less detailed relevant auction table.

im guessing this would require the name and image to be a hyperlink to the new php page, but im not sure how i can pass a php variable through the hyperlink so that the new php page can fetch details related to the item that was clicked.

so far ive got the php script to look like this:

```
<tr class = "resultindex">
        <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $ID; ?>" />
        <td class = "imgholder"><?php echo $img; ?></td>
        <td class = "infoholder">
            <div style ="height:4px;"></div>
            <div class = "infodiv"><?php echo $name; ?></div>
            <div class = "locdiv"></div>
            <div class = "userdiv"><span class="fromuser">From user: </span><br/><?php echo $owner; ?></div>
        </td>
```

where the php variables are fields fetched from a mysql database. i want to be able to pass the hidden input $ID through the hyperlink, so the new php page can retrieve the info from mysql again using it as a reference, and populate a more detailed information page
how might this be done?

Comment: You don't HAVE a hyperlink in that HTML.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a hyperlink combined with some `GET` functionality to achieve what you want like this:

```
$id=4; // assume ID of some item you want to link to
$href="<a href='somePHPPage.php?myID=".$id."'>some text</a>";
echo $href; // will output the hyperlink in your page.
```

Then in the page you can query the data that is sent like this:

```
$idYouWant=$_REQUEST['myID'];
// dp stuff with this variable to display the correct item...
```